# Update database version in Lua

Tags: database, compiler-construction, lua, coronasdk, pragma

I'm trying to update the database version but, I'm facing a strange problem...
Here's my code:

```
version = 2
local cur_db_version=nil
for data in db:nrows("PRAGMA user_version") do
    cur_db_version=data
    break
end
local db_version=cur_db_version.user_version
print(db_version)
print(version)
if (db_version~=version) then
    create()
    db:exec("PRAGMA user_version="..version)
end
```

Imagining that the database version is `1`, I'm expecting that my script prints this:

```
1
2
```

But what it is printing is:

```
2
2
```

Why? I don't know but, I do know that if I comment the line `db:exec("PRAGMA user_version="..version)`, then it really prints this:

```
1
2
```

So, what's wrong in my code that causes the wrong output? Is the line `db:exec("PRAGMA user_version="..version)` somehow being executed before the prints? If so, how can I change my code in order that it only calls `create()` when `version` changes?

By the way, I'm using Corona SDK but, I don't believe that the problem is related to it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue... The above code is correct and the problem was with a script that I have on `sublime` to relaunch the simulator when I save the file and what was happenning is that somehow, the script was relaunching the simulator 2 consecutive times and due to the many prints that I have, I didn't saw the correct output above on the console...

I will keep this question here just because there could be someone else that want to know how to update the database version on corona/lua.

Comment: It might be relaunching because of the Corona Simulator preference `Relaunch on Project Modified` or something like that... Just thought I'd add a thought :)

Comment: That's true, it was because of that. I had a script that before this new release of the simulator, was simulating a manual relaunch but now, I changed it to only focus the Simulator Window.