# selectively upgrade existing sqlite database in corona by comparing database versions

Tags: coronasdk

i would like to write code to upgrade an existing sqlite database during app updates. Also i'd like to selectively update only a few tables while leaving out a few. Does corona have anything that allows us to compare version codes and the upgrade happens only if current db version is higher than the previous db version. I have searched corona forums as well as stackoverflow and google but did not come across anything relevant. Closest match was this post:[Update database version in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495728/update-database-version-in-lua)

However the process is not clear. I'm new to Corona and would be thankful for any helpful pointers!

Comment: What did you try?  How did it go?  What did you expect?   

The article you linked to looks like a great resource for what you want.  But we need to know what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi Fernker, thanks for your reply, I was looking for something inbuilt in corona which would allow the database handling like version checking, database copying,updating tables selectively but then i figured out that Corona does not have anything like this inbuilt so i'll try the example in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495728/update-database-version-in-lua and see how it goes and will post updates, thanks!